# ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I have this line of code which is a wrapper function even though it works fine,
`const to = (promise: any) => promise.then((data: any) => data).catch((err: any) => err);`

but eslint is prompting the unexpected any error, if i do not include eslint-disable-next-line

`ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)`

the function wrapper `to()` can be used to wrap different login methods for example this function,

```
const loginWithEmail = async (email:string, password:string) => new Promise((reject) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();
  firebase.login({
    email,
    password,
  }).catch((error) => {
    reject(error);
    return error.message;
  });
});
```

and the end result is placed inside a React Component where it will get the err message and place it into a hook to be displayed.

```
  const handleEmailLogin = async () => {
    const err = await to(loginWithEmail(email, password));
    setEmailLoginError(err.message);
  };
```

i was wondering if there's a better way to define the function `to()` without relying on the type `any`?

Answer (score 0):

The `.then` is completely superfluous, since it returns the value the Promise resolved with - just use the original Promise.

The `.catch` turns the rejected value into a resolved value, without doing anything else with it. This is exceedingly strange to do IMO - do you really want to ignore errors ? - but if you do want to do this, then simply omit the type parameter entirely for the `err` (and it'll be typed as `unknown`).

The promise should be typed as `Promise<unknown>` to indicate that it's a Promise that could resolve to any value.

```
const to = (promise: Promise<unknown>) => promise.catch(err => err);
```

But it'd probably make more sense to remove the `to` function entirely.

Your `loginWithEmail` function looks somewhat broken too. `.login` returns a Promise, so there's no need to [construct another one around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - and the return value of the `.catch` isn't used elsewhere, so `return error.message` isn't doing anything.

Consider just

```
const loginWithEmail = (email:string, password:string) =>
  getFirebase()
    .login({
        email,
        password,
    });
```

Comment: yes i would agree with that, but i need the error messages returned.  good point though, i got no idea why the `to()` was written either it was a utility which served no meaning, so i decided to remove it and handle the error return directly on the function itself.